# Selecting a row based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a select statement in SQL. The select statement is selecting a licenseNo and a LicenseID. Basically, I want it to return the LicenseNo depending on which LicenseTypeID it is.

For example, I want it to return the LicenseNo if the LicenseTypeID = 6 first, then if there is no ID that equals 6, return the LicenseNo where the LicenseTypeID = 5 and so on.

Right now, I have a join that is causing multiple LicenseNos to be returned because there are multiple LicenseTypeIDs. I only want it to return the LicenseNo and row in which the ID of 6 takes precedence, then 5, then 4 and so on. It looks something like this right now:

```
Select a.Name,
       a.addressNo,
       b.LicenseNo,
       LicenseTypeID
  from addressbook a 
  join licenses b
    on a.addressNo = b.addressNo

Returns
111    CompanyA  1234   6
111    CompanyA  2222   4
```

So I only want it to return the first row, and if that ID doesnt exist (6) I want it to return the second row of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subselect to determine the maximum licence number for each address:

```
select 
  a.name,
  a.addressno,
  l.licenseno,
  l.licensetypeid
from addressbook a 
join licenses l on l.addressno = a.addressno
where l.licenseno =
(
  select max(licenseno)
  from licenses
  where licenses.addressno = a.addressno
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY l.licenseno ORDER BY l.licenseno DESC) NO,
       a.Name,
       a.addressNo,
       b.LicenseNo,
       LicenseTypeID
  from addressbook a 
  join licenses b
    on a.addressNo = b.addressNo) AS t WHERE no = 1
```